# How can i get the previous frame as a RenderTexture inside of the OnRenderImage function in HLSL Unity shaders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, hlsl, fragment-shader

I'm applying a custom fullscreen shader to my scene by setting a material and passing to it my shader, then trying to send to it the previous frame stored in a RenderTexture variable to be outputted to the screen (this is just for testing purposes)

My issue is that, when doing so, the screen becomes black and doesn't really show the previous frame like i want it to.

My curent C# code is the following:

```
private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture target) {

    if (activateShader) {
        if (previousFrameTexture == null || previousFrameTexture.width + 
            previousFrameTexture.height != src.width + src.height) {

            previousFrameTexture = new RenderTexture(src.width, src.height, 0, src.format);
            previousFrameTexture.Create();
        }

        if (material == null) material= new Material(shader);

        material.SetTexture("_PreviousFrame", previousFrameTexture);
        RenderTexture temp = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(src.width, src.height, 0, src.format);
        
        Graphics.Blit(null, temp, material);
        Graphics.Blit(temp, previousFrameTexture);
        Graphics.Blit(previousFrameTexture, target);

        RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(temp);
    } else {
        previousFrameTexture = null;
        Graphics.Blit(src, target);
    }
}
```

In my shader I'm not doing anything in particular for now, I'm just outputting the content of "_PreviousFrame" to the screen (again, just for testing purposes).
Any help would be appreciated since I just started with Unity Shaders (even though i already have experience with other types).